# How to filter results in Chrome omnibox to only show bookmarks?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, address-bar

In Firefox, if you type `*` after text in the address bar, it filters out all results except for your bookmarks, which is incredibly useful.

Is it possible to enable this feature in Chrome?

Comment: This extension - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nmkgaalbomjiafnenbknaoeilejnhnce - might be useful for you

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can achieve similar results with various extensions available.

See, for example, the [Bookmark Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-search/hhmokalkpaiacdofbcddkogifepbaijk?hl=en) or [Quickmarks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quickmarks/piefpokhpcehbeelhohgcnbipnfkogig) extensions for Google Chrome. More examples can be found by browsing the related tab on any of the two options here.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [Fauxbar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fauxbar/hibkhcnpkakjniplpfblaoikiggkopka?hl=en-US) or [Fauxbar Lite](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fauxbar-lite/bfimmnpbjccjihohjkimphfmmebffbmk?hl=en-US) for anyone looking for functionality and options similar to Firefox. It basically replaces the Omnibox with Firefox's Awesome bar and includes the same algorithm to rank search autocomplete/ search results.

The difference between the Full and Lite versions is that the full version includes it's own New Tab page that supersedes Chrome's, the Lite version does not. That's all. It took a couple minutes to go through all the settings to get it as minimal and straight forward as I wanted it, but it's well worth it and working great. There's also a [Fauxbar Memory Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fauxbar-memory-helper/domhiadbdhomljcdankobiglghedagkm?hl=en-US) extension if you keep Chrome open for long periods of time.